# Read and Show .Json file in an auto-complete search using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made a json file contain City names of a country.I want to show these City name as autocomplete search on View using MVC.My Cityname.Json file look like this -

```
Cityname[
{
    "id": 1,
    "City": "Flensburg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "City": "Kiel"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "City": "Lübeck"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "City": "Neumünster"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "City": "Brunsbüttel"
}
]
```

My model Class for City object is-

```
public class City
{
    public string id{get:set;}
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In my home controller in action-result index I desrialize Json file to show on view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<CityName> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CityName>>(json);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Now View class I made search box , where I want to get all city name in auto-completed way. But i am not how to proceed with it

```
  <div class="search-form">
    <form action="index.html" method="get">
      <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Location Name"  name="search" id="CitySearch" class="form-control input-lg">


        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/App_Data/Cityname.josn">

                $(function () {

                    $("#CitySearch").autocomplete

                });


            </script>


                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">


                 <a href="~/Home/Search">Search</a>

              </button>
           </div>
       </div>

   </form>
```

My _Layout.cshtml file look like this-

```
 @using OpenStreetMapService.Helpers
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

 <title>Call List Service | @ViewBag.Title</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Add local styles, mostly for plugins css file -->
@if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
{@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)}

<!-- Add jQuery Style direct - used for jQGrid plugin -->
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Primary Inspinia style -->
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/font-awesome/css")

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Skin configuration box -->
        @*@Html.Partial("_SkinConfig")*@

        <!-- Wrapper-->
        <!-- PageClass give you ability to specify custom style for specific view based on action -->
        <div id="wrapper" class="@Html.PageClass()">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

            <!-- Page wraper -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg @ViewBag.SpecialClass">

                <!-- Top Navbar -->
            @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

                <!-- Main view  -->
            @RenderBody()

                <!-- Footer -->
            @Html.Partial("_Footer")

            </div>
            <!-- End page wrapper-->
            <!-- Right Sidebar -->
            @Html.Partial("_RightSidebar")

        </div>
        <!-- End wrapper-->
        <!-- Section for main scripts render -->
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @*@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js")*@
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/slimScroll")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inspinia")

        <!-- Skin config script - only for demo purpose-->
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/skinConfig")

        <!-- Handler for local scripts -->
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to write server-side code to fetch this constant autocomplete data into your text box. You can use lightweight front-end tools like jQuery, which will read your JSON file and display inside autocomplete. See http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step for a good example. Just focus on JSON and JavaScript parts of the link content.

Comment: @mhmtztmr: as per your given website I have stored my Cityname.json in the app_Data folder and modified my javascript in the coding section. but is is not working

Comment: @mhmtztmr: Hi I am just trying but not getting any result with my code. Can you please check and tell me waht should I do to get City name in autosearch

Answer (score 1):

Of course a better design method can be preferred but basicly:

Put this script code inside the `<head>` tag of your HTML code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#cities").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON("citynames.json", request, function(data) {
                    var i, suggestions = [];
                    $.each(data.cities, function(i, val) {
                        if (val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                            suggestions.push({
                                label: val.name,
                                value: val.id
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    response(suggestions);
               });
           }
       });
   });
</script>
</head>
```

Add this HTML code into your View file:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="cities">Cities: </label>
    <input id="cities" />
</div>
```

And put this JSON file into the same directory with the file where you put the script above naming it as 'citynames.json':

```
{
  "cities": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Flensburg"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Kiel"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Lübeck"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Neumünster"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Brunsbüttel"
  }]
}
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y3WlvEERva7xLLfNkmWq?p=preview) for a running example

Comment: Thank you. but this code is running only with plunker . but while trying in my Visual studio it is not working at all. I am trying but not finding what is actual fault of not running this code.

Comment: Do you see a text box in the browser when you run the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. and it is searching but not showing any places as like in plunker

Comment: Just to make sure...Did you put the scripts inside the head tag, and the json file inside the same directory? No new head tag. You should add the script inside the already existing head tag in the project, most probably inside shared view.

Comment: I added my _layout.cshtml in the question section and gave the new index,cshtml in the answer section. I need to modify some points from your code. Because with your code i could not also get searching view on window. However this code while writing it starts searching but never show any places.

Comment: @mhmtzh21, Could you plaese explain me what do you mean by same directory. I saved my Cityname.json inside the view folder in home view.

Comment: Your script must find the json file where it is. `$.getJSON("citynames.json", request, function(data) {`. For this code, if you just give the json file name as "citynames.json", citynames.json file must be in the same folder with the file containing this code. If you put the json file  here: "~/App_Data", then your code must be: `$.getJSON("~/App_Data/citynames.json", request, function(data) {`. If this does not work either, I do not know any other solution buddy.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't put any code additional to the question into the answer. Just edit the question and add your code out there!

Answer (score 1):

-- Js Code ------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetCityList",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null && data != undefined) {
                    $('#cityId').typeahead({
                        source: data,
                        autoSelect: true
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

--- Controller ---

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetCityList()
        {
            string text;
            var fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\NLogErrors\File.Json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            List<City> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(text);
            return Json(items);
        }
```

--- Model ---

```
public class City
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

--- JSON File Format ---

```
[
{
    "value": 1,
    "name": "Flensburg"
},
{
    "value": 2,
    "name": "Kiel"
},
{
    "value": 3,
    "name": "Lübeck"
},
{
    "value": 4,
    "name": "Neumünster"
},
{
    "value": 5,
    "name": "Brunsbüttel"
}
]
```

--- HTML ---

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="cityId" /> (same way you can use it with razor.)
```

**I have Used bootstrap3-typeahead.js for autosuggest binding**

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON list is static data you can store a list in the javascript if that's easier.

```js
$(function() {
  var Cityname = [{
    "value": 1,
    "label": "Flensburg"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "label": "Kiel"
  }, {
    "value": 3,
    "label": "Lübeck"
  }, {
    "value": 4,
    "label": "Neumünster"
  }, {
    "value": 5,
    "label": "Brunsbüttel"
  }]
  $("#city").autocomplete({
    source: Cityname
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="city">
```

Comment: Could you please explain a liitle bit more. Where can I modified this code into my code. Sorry but I am very new handling this situation.

Comment: The input value will be posted with the form and available on the controller. I would start by looking at some tutorials on the basics of submitting forms using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

My new Index.cshtml file look like this-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
       $("#cities").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("Cityname.json", request, function (data) {
                var i, suggestions = [];
                $.each(data.cities, function (i, val) {
                    if (val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        suggestions.push({
                            label: val.name,
                            value: val.id
                        });
                    }
                });
                response(suggestions);
            });
          }
       });
    });
 </script>

   <div class="search-form">
    <form action="index.html" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter City Name" name="cities" input id="cities" class="form-control input-lg">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
                <a href="~/Home/Search">Search</a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```